# Why model with one GRU layer return zero gradients?

Tags: deep-learning, pytorch, recurrent-neural-network, gradient-descent

I'm trying to compare between 2 models in order to learn about the behaviour of the gradients.

```
import torch
import torch.nn as nn
import torchinfo

class MyModel(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self):
        super(MyModel, self).__init__()        
        self.Identity =  nn.Identity ()
        self.GRU      = nn.GRU(input_size=3, hidden_size=32, num_layers=2, batch_first=True)
        self.fc       = nn.Linear(32, 5)
        
    def forward(self, input_series):
                
        self.Identity(input_series)
        
        output, h = self.GRU(input_series)                
        output    = output[:,  -1, :]       # get last state                        
        output    = self.fc(output) 
        output    = output.view(-1, 5, 1)   # reorginize output        
                        
        return output
    
    
class SecondModel(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self):
        super(SecondModel, self).__init__()        
        self.GRU      = nn.GRU(input_size=3, hidden_size=32, num_layers=2, batch_first=True)        
        
    def forward(self, input_series):
                
        output, h = self.GRU(input_series)                                        
        return output
```

Checking the gradient of the first model gives True (zero gradients):

```
model = MyModel()
x     = torch.rand([2, 10, 3])
y     = model(x)
y.retain_grad()  
y[:, -1].sum().backward()
print(torch.allclose(y.grad[:, :-1], torch.tensor(0.)))  # gradients w.r.t previous outputs are zeroes
```

Checking the gradient of the second model **also** gives True (zero gradients):

```
model = SecondModel()
x     = torch.rand([2, 10, 3])
y     = model(x)
y.retain_grad()  
y[:, -1].sum().backward()
print(torch.allclose(y.grad[:, :-1], torch.tensor(0.)))  # gradients w.r.t previous outputs are zeroes
```

According to the answer here:

> [Do linear layer after GRU saved the sequence output order?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74951904/do-linear-layer-after-gru-saved-the-sequence-output-order/74967468?noredirect=1#comment132305941_74967468)

the second model (with just GRU layer) need to give non zero gradients.

1. What am I missing ?
2. When will we get zero or non-zero gradients ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The value of `y.grad[:, :-1]` theoretically shouldn't be zeroes, but here they are because `y[:, :-1]` doesn't seem to refer to the same tensor objects used to compute `y[:, -1]` in the GRU implementation. As an illustration, a simple 1-layer GRU implementation looks like

```py
import torch
import torch.nn as nn

class GRU(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, input_size, hidden_size):
        super().__init__()
        self.lin_r = nn.Linear(input_size + hidden_size, hidden_size)
        self.lin_z = nn.Linear(input_size + hidden_size, hidden_size)
        self.lin_in = nn.Linear(input_size, hidden_size)
        self.lin_hn = nn.Linear(hidden_size, hidden_size)
        self.hidden_size = hidden_size

    def forward(self, x):
        bsz, len_, in_ = x.shape
        h = torch.zeros([bsz, self.hidden_size])
        hs = []
        for i in range(len_):
            r = self.lin_r(torch.cat([x[:, i], h], dim=-1)).sigmoid()
            z = self.lin_z(torch.cat([x[:, i], h], dim=-1)).sigmoid()
            n = (self.lin_in(x[:, i]) + r * self.lin_hn(h)).tanh()
            h = (1.-z)*n + z*h
            hs.append(h)

        # Return the output both as a single tensor and as a list of
        # tensors actually used in computing the hidden vectors
        return torch.stack(hs, dim=1), hs
```

Then, we have

```py
model = GRU(input_size=3, hidden_size=32)
x = torch.rand([2, 10, 3])
y, hs = model(x)
y.retain_grad()
for h in hs:
    h.retain_grad()
y[:, -1].sum().backward()
print(torch.allclose(y.grad[:, -1], torch.tensor(0.)))  # False, as expected (sanity check)
print(torch.allclose(y.grad[:, :-1], torch.tensor(0.)))  # True, unexpected
print(any(torch.allclose(h.grad, torch.tensor(0.)) for h in hs))  # False, as expected
```

It appears PyTorch computes the gradients w.r.t all tensors in `hs` as expected but not those w.r.t `y`.

So, to answer your question:

1. I don't think you miss anything. The linked answer is just not quite right as it incorrectly assumes PyTorch would compute `y.grad` as expected.
2. The theory given as a comment in the linked answer is still right, but not quite complete: gradient is *always* zero iff the input doesn't matter.